# Fetching images on to the browser

Tags: jquery, sql, html, css, nosql

I am working on designing a Photography website(In the website i will be posting hundreds of high quality pics) using HTML5, CSS3, Jquery. After completion of coding am going to host it through 'godaddy' servers. I have completed most of designing part and i have problem in dealing with image storage and rendering. Please keep note that hundreds of images and around 4MB of size each.

** EDIT **

I am editing my question to be more specific. i am familiar with SQL and i heard about **NoSql** but dont know how efficient is it for this task.  **Which is the best way to deal with images in this situation?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Thnx for quick reply Dean. I need help in dealing with images in my site. My apologies for not using 'wh' words in my question :)

Comment: this question will probably generate only opinion-based answers, obviously you will need to think what are your needs, if you will need more info/data on pictures you will mix it, putting data in a DB and retrieving the image by name from the folder

Answer (score 3):

never store image bytes to DB. the best way to do this, and is the standard implementation, is to store images' URLs to the DB. save images in a folder and store their urls to DB

Comment: Isn 't that a matter of opinion?  Some DBAs I know whould strongly disagree!

Comment: yes it is. and I agree with you, :) This user is just looking for an immediate answer and might as well help him with it.

Comment: totally agreed with @Mongskie, dont upload the pic to db and in user case since image is of 4MB it would make your database large in size, Upload it to your server and save the link to a particular image in your db, make sure you dont upload your pic in temp folder.